# How to upload all images stored in a file of internal memory

Tags: android

I need to send all images stored in a file. Now am sending one image on button click by specifying its name. But how to send all images on button click saved in some folder

```
public class UploadImagesToServer {


public static void postImage(String ImageLink){

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    try {
        params.put("file", new File(ImageLink));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AsyncHttpClient mNewCaller = new AsyncHttpClient();


    mNewCaller.get(Constants.MediaUpload, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            Log.e("response page", response.toString());


        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseString);
            Log.e("frag", responseString + " " + statusCode);

        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray responseString) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseString);
            Log.e("frag", responseString + " " + statusCode);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
            Log.e("fail 3", statusCode + "" + errorResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
            Log.e("fail 3", statusCode + "" + responseString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONArray errorResponse) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
            Log.e("fail 3", statusCode + "" + errorResponse);
        }
    });

}
```

}

the above code is for sending an image

```
    continueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "/Omoto Images/background image.jpg";
            UploadImagesToServer.postImage(filePath);
        }
    });
```

this is for calling postImage method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best process for uploading multiple images.
Your image uploading code already implemented you need to just change flow.

You could store your image paths in a list (or something similar) and save the 
list (it may be shared preference or sqlite). 
As you finish uploading a picture, remove it from that list and continue to the next one, and so on upto your list is empty.

When uploading, if the internet connection drops it will not affect you, 
you will always have save the list of images that are still to be uploaded.

For get all images path:
You need to scan directory and store image path and before uploading check path file is exist or not because sometime image may be removed or move.